# How to convert 10ms ticks value into seconds using Java?

Tags: java, time

As part of my requirement I need to convert the given decimal value which is measured in 10ms ticks into seconds.

Example values are: 437540, 1207959583, 9468

Need some help in how to convert this value into seconds using Java?

Comment: 1 second = 1000 milliseconds = 100 ticks of 10 milliseconds. In other words: Divide by 100.

Comment: Well 10ms is .01 seconds, so divide by 100?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, but a very simple arithmetic question.

Comment: This is just simple arithmetic

Comment: I was bit confused with the ticks. Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 1000ms in a second. `1000 / 10` is `100`. Divide the number of `10 ms` ticks by `100` and you'll have the number of seconds.

Comment: I was bit confused with the ticks. Thanks for response.